# Angular redirects when I hit enter in an input field

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following application with an input field. When I type in and hit enter, the app forwards to `http://example.org/?`. Rather than firing the `onEnter` event. The onKey event work fine. How can I stop this redirecting happening?

here is the html:

```
<mat-card>
  <form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="How can I help" (keyup)="onKey($event)">
      <mat-icon matSuffix>?</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

and the ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  onKey(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: use <input matInput placeholder="How can I help" (keydown.enter)="doSomething();return false">

Comment: @Eliseo NB the doSomething function does fire correctly, but the application redirects to the `/?` route straight after.

Comment: Unless if you are redirecting this should not happen

Answer (score 1):

check type of button , if any type is not given then it takes type="submit" by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting the old fashion way, you can avoid this by adding a `return false;` at the end of the function.

```
onKey(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value)
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by missing FormsModule and HttpModule modules in the app.module.ts

```js
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,// import FormsModule
    HttpModule,// import HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The form is submitting when you hit enter. This behavior is the default.  By definition, a form is submittable. Given that, register a submit handler for your form to  control what it means for the form to be submitted.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent {
  onSubmit() {

  }
  onKey(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }
}
```

Now, in your template

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes weird behaviors come from sources we don't guess. I think everything in question mentioned above is correct, an elsewhere side effect causes this problem. Check something like route guards... or parent component input handlings...

Answer (score -1):

I recently had the same issue and not sure why this happens. To solve this I had to use Angulars way of handling forms.

I used the formbuilder in my case:

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  searchForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder){  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.searchForm = this._fb.group({
      'search':['']
    });
  }

  submit(){ 
    console.log(this.searchForm);
  }

  onKeyup($event){
    console.log($event)
  }
}


<mat-card>
  <form class="example-form" [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="How can I help" fromControlName="search" (keyup)="onKeyup($event)">
      <mat-icon matSuffix>?</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: The choice between template-driven forms and reactive forms has nothing to do with avoiding accidental submission.